# Loading ACF Field content on a 404.php page

Tags: pages, advanced-custom-fields, 404-error

I am trying to load a ACF Field from a page to my 404.php but i cannot get it to work.

get_post_field works fine but get_field does not

```
<?php

/**
 * The template for displaying 404 pages (not found)
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page
 *
 * @package test
 */

get_header();
$post_id = 6018; // Post ID 
$acf_field = get_field('text', $post_id); // get acf field 'text' from post

?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area container">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <section class="error-404 not-found">
            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo get_post_field('post_content', $post_id); ?></h1> <!-- Does something -->
            </header>

            <div class="page-content">
                <?php
                get_search_form();
                ?>
                <?php echo $acf_field ?> <!-- Does nothing -->
            </div>
        </section>

    </main>
</div>


<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: You're sure `text` is the full name of the field, and it contains data? Have you tried `var_dump($acf_field)` in case it's not just a string?

Comment: var_dump returns NULL which is really weird.

Comment: also get_fields($post_id) returns bool(false)

Comment: I'd check the database to make sure that post ID is valid (exists in `wp_posts`). If so, I'd then check the postmeta table to see if it contains any fields for that post ID.